# Ng-repeat in Protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a page that displays a list of questions using ng-repeat.

How can I use ng-repeat in protractor. Below is the code we have written to display the questions. I want to access the question using protractor.

```
<div class="" ng-class="{ }"  ng-repeat="qList in List">

    <md-radio-group
            ng-model="qList.choiceId"
            id="q{{$index}}"
            name="q{{$index}}">
        <md-radio-button value="{{aList.cId}}"
                         aria-label="{{aList.cText}}" ng-repeat="aList in qList.oChoiceList">

        </md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var List = element.all(by.repeater('qList in List'));
```

**The total questions are get into a variable *List*, then you can access to questions by index of the question. like if you want access in to first question, the code is like**
. **First Question  `List.get(0);`
Second Question:** `List.get(1);`

Comment: Hi, i tried the way you mentioned, but its giving error "unexpected token ILLEGAL" , below the actual code im using to get the qList from List. Please let me what would is wrong in this .                                               var list=element.all(by.repeater('qList in app.appProdList[0].
      prodDesc.data.List'));

Comment: hi, in the above code there is no repeater with ('qList in app.appProdList[0]. prodDesc.data.List')

Comment: no repeater ? , i have used by.repeater , can you please update my code with the code im missing.

Comment: in the above code there is no binding to display the question.